# Is there a way to add Memoji characters to the keyboard of a TextEditor with SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, memoji

I have a SwiftUI app that allows users to enter text in a TextEditor.  I need to use a multiline TextEditor and not a TextField.

Is there any native SwiftUI way of showing the Memoji keyboard so that the user can select Memoji characters from the Pasteboard.

I have implemented this before using UIKit previously by setting the textView allowsEditing property to true.

I don't see any similar property for a Text Editor.

Also, I know how to implement a UIViewRepresentable.  But my question and hope is that it can be done somehow natively using SwiftUI

Comment: Why is this being marked down?

Comment: Isn't Memoji is added to textView as image instead of unicode? I'm not sure

Comment: I've found this: https://kostyakulakov.ru/how-to-get-memoji-from-uitextfield-or-uitextview-swift-4/